# Mysql две таблицы, два первичных ключа, джоин, не работает индекс

Tags: mysql, myisam

Даны две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
    `city_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `enabled` ENUM('0','1') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `domain` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `cities_loc` (
    `city_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name_ro` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

В таблицах есть данные. Делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM cities c 
JOIN cities_loc cl ON c.city_id = cl.city_id
```

`EXPLAIN` данного запроса показывает что индекс не применяется, в `POSSIBLE KEYS` стоит `PRIMARY`, а по сути `KEY` - пустой, и `rows = 327`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему в этом случае не работают индексы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выполнения данного запроса придется выполнить полное сканирование таблицы, сопоставив каждой записи другую запись из "другой" таблицы. Поэтому оптимизатор решил не использовать индекс. Тем более вы извлекаете все данные.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже все понял, все из-за моей не внимательности (у меня еще было условие, по нему выбиралась одна запись, и у этого поля не было индекса)

Answer (score 1):

Ну почему, применяется.

Вы всё равно хотите **всё** из `c`, поэтому там поиск по индексу просто не имеет смысла: нет критериев. Просили все 327 строк — *получите и распишитесь*.

Но вложенный поиск, из `JOIN`'а, использует первичный ключ `cl`, чтобы каждой записи из `c` найти соответствующую по `c.city_id` запись, одну. Для этого поиска индекс уже имеет смысл и используется.